# Batch program with variables only returns zero

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a self duplicating number variable in batch. It looks like this.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set cut= 2
:A
set /a cut = %cut% * %cut%
echo %cut%
pause
goto A
```

The number will work up to 65536,but then it will only echo zero.
Any help?
thanks.

Comment: You exceed the limit of a signed 32-bit integer (which is the maximum number batch set /A can handle), 65536 -1 is the largest unsigned 16-bit number.  65536 multiplied with itself it would also exceed unsigned 32-bit number range.

Comment: Batch math is limited to signed 32-bit integers. 65536*65536 is 2^33, which is a 1 followed by 32 zeroes. Because batch only looks at the rightmost 32 digits, all it sees is 0. Use PowerShell instead.